# Python - Variable correlation with formula

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, variables, correlation

I'm working on an array from spectral-medical data of 150 observations and 1500 variables, stored as follows (all these data are floats):

```
blood = ([[sample1_var1..., sample1_var1500],[sample2_var1..., sample2_var1500]..., [sample_150_var1..., sample150_var1500]])
```

I would like to obtain the coefficient of correlation between each variable and another variable stored in a list of 150 observations like :

```
 ery = ([1.524, 1.987..., 1.369])
```

I need to obtain the 'r' coefficient of correlation between `var1` and `ery`, then `var2` and `ery`. etc. Is there a simple way to do that (maybe with a for-loop)?

Comment: but if you want to get pairwise correlation between 1500 variables wouldn't it be 1500x1500 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that:

- `blood` has 1500 variables and 150 observations
- `ery` is a 1d array/list (you actually have it as a 1-element tuple in your question)
- You want to find 1500 correlations (correlation of each variable in `blood` to the vector `ery`)

Using pandas and NumPy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

blood = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(150,1500)).add_prefix('var')
# blood.shape = (150, 1500)
ery = pd.Series(np.random.rand(150))
print(blood.corrwith(ery))
var0      -0.12897
var1      -0.16448
var2       0.02315
var3      -0.09275
var4      -0.00337
var5       0.00094
var6      -0.13884
var7      -0.04296
var8       0.11895
var9       0.01626
var10      0.04122
var11     -0.04241

var1488    0.12936
var1489   -0.14607
var1490    0.14229
var1491    0.06072
var1492   -0.00815
var1493    0.03401
var1494   -0.00994
var1495   -0.10997
var1496    0.05980
var1497   -0.00930
var1498    0.05205
var1499   -0.11258
dtype: float64
```

Troubleshooting: it helps to specify what data structures you're working with in your question.  The way you have things now is ambiguous.  If `ery` is a list, you'll need `blood.corrwith(pd.Series(ery))`.